# Xcode 7.3 <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h> & <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h> file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, core-telephony, xcode7.3

I am running project since long time.Suddenly it start giving error. I have just update Xcode to 7.3 create certificates and upload App at iTunes for Test flight. Now When I run project, it gives error "CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h file not found".
I have removed these files and run again, This time it gives "CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h file not found".

[image]

Framework already exist in App

[image]

- I have clean and rebuild project, restart xcode, restart pc.
- I have added "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" line to "Header Search Paths".
  But nothing has worked, So how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth and CoreTelephony don't exist on Watch OS 2.x. Here is my tips for this:

- Define your preprocessor macro on project setting. In my case is APPLE_WATCH=1
- Your code now should be something like this

> ```
> #ifndef APPLE_WATCH
>    // YOUR CODE HERE
> #endif
> ```